# More Effective Way to Store Schedule in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that stores schedules of around 250 days for around 1,300 users. It consists of a user column, date column and a location column.

Currently, about 250 days are repeated around 1,300 times, where in the user column, the username is repeated all 250 times for each day, where the location and date will vary. Is there a more effective way to store the locations of each user every day without repeating the username in a table? This current method works well right now though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your users are a separate entity and should have their own table. This way, if any user name changes, you don't have to edit every event the user is attending.

You can link the user to their events by creating a unique identifier for each user, then replacing the username column in the events table with a user id column.

This is the tip of the iceberg of relational database normalisation; a technique for ensuring your database is robust and flexible by reducing the amount of redundant or duplicate data.

Comment: Currently, by username I mean a unique 7 digit ID. I'm wondering if the table can be shrunk any more than that

Comment: At that point you're looking at optimising the data types of your fields to use less memory. If that's your question you should ask a new one.